iTextSharp - Add new page when page not fully completed
In iTextSharp, when the page is full a new page is created automatically
But I need the new page is created only when the previous page size not full until last line,
but before fully completed
This is code:
    Document document = new Document();  

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("D:/folder/me.pdf", FileMode.Create));  
    
    document.Open();  

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello World");  

        document.Add(para); 
    }

    document.Close();  

In the above code when the first page is full content a new page is created
I need when content of page reach specific size of page a new page created, not when page content is full

If by "reach specific size of page" you mean reaching a specific y coordinate on the page, you can simply set the margins accordingly, in particular the bottom margin, to that coordinate.
